# Browser refresh causes multiple form submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, browser

I have the below code in my jsp where we enter subject and message and click on a button which causes form submit, when we do a page refresh by clicking F5, it is causing multiple form submissions.

I added the below line $('form').preventDoubleSubmission(); and the function corresponding to it in my jsp but it is still not working. Please assist.

```
   function validateXYZ() { 
    var frm = document.forms["update-xyz"];
    frm.actionType.value=message;
    if (message == "submit_new") {
    if (frm.subject.value == "" || frm.content.value == "") {
        alert ("Please fill in Subj and Msg");
        return false;
    }
}  
   $('form').preventDoubleSubmission();
    frm.submit();
  }

  //jQuery plugin to prevent double submission of forms
   /*jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function() {
     $(this).on('submit',function(e){
      var $form = $(this);
  if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
    // Previously submitted - don't submit again
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // Mark it so that the next submit can be ignored
    $form.data('submitted', true);
  }
});
```

Thanks,
Praseel.

Comment: frm.submit() bypasses the jquery bound event bound by preventDoubleSubmission. Not to mention, it won't stop refreshing the page from reposting the data (since the content of the page depends on posting said data at that point)

Comment: Can you redirect the user after the post? Maybe even to the same page. So if they press f5 it will just refresh the page.

Comment: Hi MyP3uK, Thank you for the information.Do I need to redirect within the action class, usually we do it as response.sendRedirect(), Do i need to do this before I return forward from the method in my action class? How can I get the response object in struts2 action class?.

Comment: Hi Kevin, In that case Do I need to remove the frm.submit() or this solution wouldnt work at all?Please let me know

Comment: frm.submit() is called when the user clicks a button which calles validateXYZ() and submit within

Comment: I removed the call $('form').preventDoubleSubmission(); and I have added the below code before and after frm.submit();but its not working; Why is not redirecting to this URL. Please help                                                                 <%
      String redirectURL = "http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/";
         response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
     %>